# nftables support string matching support

Tags: nftables

Iptables can match packets by string.

Example for dns:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -m string --hex-string "|09|proxypipe|03|net" --algo bm -j DROP
```

How to perform such matching in nftables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With nftables, you can use Raw Payload Expression syntax (documented [here](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/nftables/nft.8.en.html)) to match a packet based on the contents of a chunk of bits.

So, a rule to block queries for `proxypipe.net` would look like this:

```
meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 @th,160,120 0x0970726f787970697065036e657400 counter drop comment "block queries for proxypipe.net"
```

The above would grab 120 bits worth of data, starting from bit 160 of the transport header (`@th`), and compare them to the hex equivalent of `|09|proxypipe|03|net`

Note that unlike the iptables version, the above would only match `proxypipe.net` at a fixed position in the packet. This means that it wouldn't block `foobar.proxypipe.net` or any other subomains.